# ExtJS refresh after delete is successful

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm working with ExtJS, and when i delete a row in grid, i want it to refresh automatically. But so far without luck.
This is my grid, and at the end is delete function

```
Ext.define('CrudExt.view.usuario.Grid',{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    title       : 'Lista brandova',
    itemId      : 'usuarioGrid',
    xtype       : 'usuariogrid',
    store       : 'Usuarios',
    initComponent: function(){

        this.columns = [
            { header: 'Sifra',  dataIndex: 'sifra' },
            { header: 'Brand', dataIndex: 'brand'}
        ];

        this.dockedItems = [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'top',
                items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Dodaj',
                    iconCls: 'add',
                    action: 'add'
                },
                {
                    text    : 'Izbriši brand',
                    tooltip: 'Stisni za izbrisati brand.',
                    iconCls: 'delete',
                    itemId: 'delete',
                    scope: this,
                    handler: this.onDeleteClick
                },
                {
                    text: 'Izmjeni',
                    iconCls: 'edit',
                    action: 'edit'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            store: 'Usuarios',
            dock: 'bottom',
            displayInfo: true
        }
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments);
},

   onDeleteClick: function(grid){
    Ext.Msg.show({
         title:'Confirm Delete',
         msg: 'Deleting this document will delete ALL users associated with this group.<br />ARE YOU SURE? Press "Yes" to delete.',
         buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
         fn: processResult,
         icon: Ext.MessageBox.WARNING,
         scope: this
       });
    function processResult(buttonId){
        if (buttonId == 'yes'){
              var selection = this.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
              var rev = selection.get('sifra');

              Ext.Ajax.request
              ({
                 url : 'brand/delete/'+rev,
                 success   : function(response) 
                 {

                }
              });
              //console.log(rev);
        } else {
              Ext.Msg.alert('The document has NOT been deleted');
        }
    };
}

});
```

what i did i tryed adding the following lines in success of the delte and none of them worked:

```
grid.getStore().load();
store.reload();
store.load();
store.sync();
this.getStore.load();
Ext.getCmp('usuarioGrid').getView().refresh();
grid.getView().refresh();
```

Comment: When doing `store.reload()` do you actually see the request being sent to the server in your browser's debugger ?

Comment: No it's not.
Now i tried c/p the part of refreshing from create and update which works normally in to delete and when delteing document a message pops up "You deleted the document". and store.reload() does nothing like it is not there in delete.

Comment: How do you load the store initially ? `reload` uses the last `load` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
success:function(response){
grid.store.remove(record); 
me.getStore().reload();
}
```

Worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

Find the index of the record using the [`Store.indexOf()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.Store.html#method-indexOf) method, and use the [`Store.removeAt()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.Store.html#method-removeAt) method to remove the record.

I think that might work.